# Is there any way to check if there are negative elements on the list and if so remove them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, python-requests

I have these lines here and I want to write a program that checks if there is a negative number in the list,and if so, remove it.Then, calculate the average of the 2 first elements Can someone help?

```
def test() : 
  values = [3, 6, 5, 4, -5]
```

print(values)
  return values

Answer (score 2):

Just check if a number is less than `0`:

```
def test(values):
    l = [n for n in values if n >= 0]
    return l, (l[0]+l[1])/2

print(test([3, 6, 5, 4, -5]))
```

Output:

```
[3, 6, 5, 4], 4.5
```